# Error: friends.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <, after using express.static and change html content after button click

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to display home.html on initial load of localhost:9000, but when I do when the way my current code is, I get the error: `friends.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`. I am not sure what this error means. Also, when I do windows.location = localhost:9000/list, in my display.js, the get requests will not send the list.html to the browser, and nothing changes. I tried putting the get request in both server.js and display.js but they both do nothing.

Directory layout

```
dir main
    -server.js
    dir subMain
      dir display
        -display.js
      dir routing
        -routes.js
      dir public
        -home.html
        -list.html
```

server.js

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
require('./subMain/routing/routes.js')(app, path, express);

app.listen(9000, function(){
     console.log('connected on 9000')
})



//app.get('/list', function(request, response){
       // response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/..', 'public', 'list.html'));
    //});
```

routes.js

```
module.exports = function(app, path, express){
    app.use(express.static("subMain"))
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/routing"));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/display"));
    app.use(function(request, response, next){
      response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/..", "public", "home.html"));
    })
    app.get('/list', function(request, response){
        response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/..', 'public', 'list.html'));
    });

}
```

display.js

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn', sendSurvery);

function sendSurvery(){
    window.location = 'survey.html';
    //var myQueryUrl = "http://localhost:9000/survey";

    //$.ajax({url: myQueryUrl, method: 'GET', success: function(result){
        // location.href = "http://localhost:9000/list"

    //}}).done(function(response){

    //});
}
```

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Friend Finder Home Page</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="rowOne">
        <!-- <div class="jumbotron col-lg-6"> -->
          <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
          <p>Click the button</p>
          <button id="btn" style="width: 200px;">BUTTON</button>
        <!-- </div> -->
    </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../data/friends.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't supplied your `home.html` file, but the issue you're encountering is that your `friends.js` is not being found by express, and your `home.html` file is being returned instead. The first character in your `home.html` file is `<` and this is why you're getting the error. Check you are referencing the correct path of `friends.js` and that it is present in your static assets folder.

To confirm my explanation, you can directly access the url you're using to access `friends.js` and see the contents of `home.html` returned.

Comment: what do you mean I haven't supplied my home.html? And also when I do express.static, is the path is relative or starts from where the server is being run with node, which would be server.js? So even though my code for express.static is in the path (server.js)/subMain/routing/routes.js, it starts from where server.js? If so I would have to change my express.static path to '/submain/routing'?

Comment: What I mean is that you haven't put `home.html` in your question. Use `__dirname` as per the docs to get your current working directory. From there you can work out your paths. https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname Did you look at the response you are getting when requesting `friends.js`?

Comment: Well I know friends.js is properly linked to my home.html since hte url changes from the windows.location I have in my code. But I included the home.html code in question now. As far as displaying list.html once the button is clicked, nothing happens. The error I mentioned before about the `<` does not come out anymore, but everytime I take out the code `app.use(express.static("subMain"))`  I get that error again.

Comment: So that you can mark my answer as accepted, please take a look at the `friends.js` response body when you receive `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` and see that you receive HTML, not javascript.

Comment: I dont get that error anymore when I do `app.use(express.static("subMain"))`. The friends.js is not accessed by a URL, it is linked to my home.html, unless you mean the url to the home page localhost:9000. The friends.js just has a click event that changes windows.location to `localhost:9000/list`, but even though it changes, the get request is not working. How do I look at the response body?